# onbeforemousemove to get mouse's old position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, drag-and-drop, mouse

I'm working on a drag and drop lib and i would like to add the mouse's position variation to the dragged element's actual position instead of just setting it's position to the current cursor position in the window. This would allow me not to use position: fixed and be able to drag position relative/absolute; elements.

To know the old position of the mouse (before the mousemove handler is called) i can just store the position in a variable in the previous call to that handler using e.pageX and pageY. But what about the first time the mouse handler is moved ? **How can i know the old mouse position to determine it's variation when i havn't stored that old position yet ?**

A piece of code :

```
    var $dragged = null,
        $window = $(window),
        oldMouseX = null,
        oldMouseY = null;

    var mouseMoveHandler = function(e) {
        var curTop = $dragged.css('top'),
            curLeft = $dragged.css('left');
        $dragged.css({
            top  : curTop + e.pageY - oldMouseY,
            left : curLeft + e.pageX - oldMouseX,
        });
        oldMouseX = e.pageX;
        oldMouseY = e.pageY;
    };

    $('.Draggable')

        .attr('draggable', true)

        .css({userSelect: 'none'})

        .on('mousedown', function() {
            $dragged = $(this);
            $window.bind('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
        })
        .on('mouseup', function() {
            $dragged = null;
            $window.unbind('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
        })
```

Comment: I really don't get what's being asked here. mousedown exposes the `event` object, which gives you the page x/y at that very moment, there is nothing `before` that because no event will be fired. Anything after that is captured within the `mousemove`....not sure what you need here...

Comment: I need something like e.previousPageX/Y so i can determine the position variation : e.pageX/Y - e.previousPageX/Y

Comment: That's what I'm saying....`on('mousedown', function(e){`, where the `e` gives you what you want...When you access the `e` within the mousemovehandler, that's value could be skewed